# Override setter in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want set `NSDate` from `NSInteger` and i have `@property`:

`@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDate *date;`

I want setter:

```
-(void)setDate:(NSInteger *)tStamp {
    thumbImgUrl = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:tStamp];
}
```

So i want to set my date from `NSInteger` value not `NSDate` value. How can i declare this setter? When i try to put it in header file it works ok, but i'm getting a warning:

`Type of property 'date' does not match type of accessor 'setDate:`

And if i want to declare it in *.m* file i'm getting error:

`duplicate declaration of method setDate:`

Why? There is a way to declare setter with different input type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally this is a really bad way of doing things in Objective-C, and I would highly recommend you to change your method name to something else such as `-(void)setDateWithInteger:(NSInteger)tStamp`. (Speaking of which, NSInteger is a primitive, not an object)  And to answer your question, no, there is no way to declare a setter with different input type if you use `@property`.  If you do insist doing it your way, then you will have to declare the method without using `@property`.

Comment: So to be clear. I override regular setter and in this setter calling `-(NSDate)setDateWithInteger:(NSInteger)tStamp` method? Is that a good way?

Comment: Yes, IMO that's the best way of approaching what you would want to do without creating too much confusion.

Comment: actually what @SimpleMan is suggesting in his comment is rather confusing. Just implement a `setDateWithInteger` method without overriding any setter and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accept a type of `id` as the input parameter to the setter function.

You are getting the `duplicate declaration of method setDate:` because most likely you have the line `@synthesize date` in your implementation file.  This automatically generates the getter/setters for you.  Remove that line, since you are providing your own implementation.